# Installed Ubuntu 12.04 over Windows 7 fine but now Ubuntu crashes

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I did a complete overhaul of my box and got rid of Windows and the install went very smoothly. Was very impressed with the ease of the install and the ease of use with Ubuntu.... til now.. was in a virtual world and noticed the graphics were not as nice as a Windows machine.. actually they are pretty bad so I got this wild hair and went looking for drivers and found Nvidia drivers for linux version 310 I believe..

Anyway installed the NVIDIA drivers, rebooted and the machine became really slow. Then it Black Screened on me over and over again , wouldn't even boot from CD saying "there was an internal error" and crashed.. didn't even have time to read.. so I happily reinserted the install and guess what .. dang thing won't install.. more error messages .. so I'm sitting here with a machine no OS and uh this little girl is not happy.. any help out there fellas?

Comment: Ok let me rephrase my post :) I had Ubuntu installed and running fine. Had it running for 24 hours. Not from a Live CD or as a "try it" situation. It was installed on the HD as a perm OS. and i did not run as a dual boot with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue on my own by burning at a lower speed then I had previously. I also disallowed Brasero to verify checksum at the end of the burn by disabling that plugin.

Now I am back up and running but not sure if I will risk installing nVidia drivers for linux this time, seeing as this whole Black Screen episode began after doing this in the first  place.

I will put some time into researching the error 5 issue when it comes to burn speeds and or checksum at a later time and till come back and post my results.

Comment: I did that in the past, I wrote them with slowest speed possible and it burnt better. I suggest to do NOT install 12.04 with nVidia... I had serious issues (I found NO workaround) like not being able to access my ctrl+alt+f1 text terminal. That issue is completely gone with 12.10!!! in other words, if you want to play 3D games, on a new partition of your HD, install at least 12.10 (I am thinking on 13.04 already but havent dont that yet). Also I suggest 64bit mode, my computer is much faster with 64bit! and the applications can access all my memory!

Answer (score 0):

You should Live Boot with CD or USB before installing the Ubuntu on DISK and by spending some time with ubuntu you feel it's much better then any other OS. Now, start all process from scratch

Comment: Ok to be fair, I started from scratch as Dr suggest, burned a Live CD at a lower speed to ensure integrity of the burn, I also did the USB install, and did each several times. Each time i get the error 5 input/output message. So now i fsck and check , all pass,I also check the HD, partions, look for bad sectors all the good stuff to make sure there is nothing wrong hardware wise , ect... all pass.. but still the dreaded error 5. At first I thought was a bad HD,turns out its not. Then i read forums and tried a little of everything i saw related to error 5, didnt help it install so now im blank